# Question regarding Product Rule of Derivatives

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

According to the Limit principles the $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x).g(x)$ is $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x).\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x)$.

And also the definition of Derivatives is also $f'(x)= \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

Hence the derivative of $F'(x)$ where $F(X)=f(x).g(x)$ needs to be $F'(x) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}. \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac {g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}$ i.e. $f'(x).g'(x)$ but why it is $F'(x) = f(x).g'(x)+g(x).f'(x)$

Apologies if it sounds like a stupid question

Regards,
Siddartha C.S

Comment: $$F(x)=f(x).g(x)\implies F'=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x)}{h}\\\ne  \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.\frac {g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}. \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac {g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}$$

Comment: @Holo: Thanks for the quick response. So the limit rules do not apply here? if so why?

Comment: @Siddarth There  is an essential difference. By finding the derivative $x$ is **fixed** (and $h$ varies). By finding $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ there is fixed $a$ and a **varying** $x$. Finding derivative is not a special case of what you call "limit principle",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Definition**: $$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}}$$

Let $p(x)=f(x)\cdot g(x)$, then:

$$p'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{p(x+h)-p(x)}{h}=$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x)}{h}=$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x+h)+f(x)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x)}{h}=$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{[f(x+h)-f(x)]g(x+h)+f(x)[g(x+h)-g(x)]}{h}=$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\lim_{h\to 0}g(x+h)+\lim_{h\to 0}f(x)\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}=$$
$$=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$$

Comment: I am well aware of the proof. of the derivative but just wondering why the Limit rules does not apply here?

Comment: Well, the reason is behind the definition of the derivative, it is not only a "limit" of a function, it's a limit of $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. You are taking the derivative of the entire product, that is $(fg)'$ and the result $f'g+fg'$ is what the definition gives.

Comment: You simply cannot distribute derivative over multiplication. One has $(f+g)'=f'+g'$ but $(fg)'\neq f'g'$

Comment: So I get it now. I am fooling myself thinking $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ as one function of $f(x)$ but this is a special case where limits dont apply right?

Comment: Yea, pretty much what i said. Everytime you apply some operation to something "grouped", you must have a rule for it. We know that for exponentiation $(ab)^x=a^xb^x$ But at the same time generally $(a+b)^x\neq a^x+b^x$. The very same case are the derivatives. We have that $(f+g)'=f'+g'$ but in general $(fg)'\neq f'g'$.

Comment: The limit laws are still true (they always are) you are just applying them incorrectly.

Comment: Probably you fooled yourself by thinking that: $(f(x)g(x))'=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\cdot \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}$. But the product on the r.h.s corresponds to $f'(x)\cdot g'(x)$ which is generally NOT equal to $(f(x)g(x))'$

Answer (score 1):

Try with linear (affine) functions first to see why.

That is, let $f(x+h) = f(x)+f' h$, $g(x+h) = g(x)+g' h$, then
$f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x) = (f' g(x)+ f(x)g')h + f'g'h^2$